# Image in flexbox, 100% height is too large

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I realize there are other similar questions and I apologize if this has been answered, but I haven't been able to discern a solution to my question.

https://codepen.io/benrhere/pen/GRoLqPK

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  border-style: dotted;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

h4 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>Headline inside of flexy</h4>
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/400/300" alt="image placeholder for a thumb that's supposed to present a featured work" class="work-thumb">
</div>
```

I want the image to be within the flexbox border. When I set the height of the image to 100%, it correctly sets it to the height of the parent box. But I need to account for the height of the first sibling in the div (the headline). Right now, I'm getting this:

[image]

Comment: It's nearly always better to wrap flexbox images in their own div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used a fixed height but your contain image is bigger than that. you can use both solutions.

```
div {
      min-height: 300px; /* or height:100%; */
      background-color: green;
      display: flex; 
      border-style: dotted;
      flex-direction:column;
}
```

please let me know if anything unclear to you.Happy Coding!!!

Reference: https://codepen.io/Mithunjack/pen/QWyPEep

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. It's counter intuitive to me that by setting a min height, the resulting height could actually be smaller, but that seems to be the case. I'm going to read through that other post to try to make better sense of that.

Comment: You welcome mate.

Answer (score 1):

**edit , see the duplicate for explanations**

You may also set a `min-height` (or `overflow:hidden`) on the img , so the browser recalculate the max size it can be to remain inside it's flex parent.

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  border-style: dotted;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  min-height:0;/* or 
  overflow:hidden ;
  ...  if thats speaks to you better */
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>Headline inside of flexy</h4>
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/400/300" alt="image placeholder for a thumb that's supposed to present a featured work" class="work-thumb">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful. As I wrote on the other response, it's counter intuitive to me that by setting a min height, the resulting height could actually be smaller, but that seems to be the case. I appreciate the response.

Comment: @BenjiFB if the img is not tall enough, add `flex-grow:1;` to the rules of ìmg`, it will expand it to the bottom if it is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

The image is longer than its parent (div element). You can either set a `max-height` for the img (as in the snippet) or add `height: fit-content;` to the div style.

```css
div {
      height: 300px;
      background-color: green;
      display: flex;
      border-style: dotted;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    img {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-height: 240px;
    }
```

```html
<div>
      <h4>Headline inside of flexy</h4>
      <img src="https://loremflickr.com/400/300" alt="image placeholder for a thumb that's supposed to present a featured work" class="work-thumb">
    </div>
```

Comment: This solution didn't seem to work for me. Setting min-height, instead of max-height, did tho.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, though.